# gauss map differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Ok, this may not be a very smart question but i thought about asking it anyway.  The question came up from an excercise i was trying but i m hoping for something more general. Let $r(x,y)=(x, y, xy), x,y \in R $. Prove that the Gauss map is the up hemisphere of the sphere, meaning the sphere for $z>0$.
So, you easilly find that the vertical vector is $n(x,y)=1/\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} (-y, -x, 1).$ You know that this is part of the sphere and you see that indeed $z>0$, so we are in the up hemisphere but then i kinda have a hard time showing that it can fill up the whole up hemisphere. I can do it by showing it s 1-1 and onto but i think it s too complicated. I know it s trivial but is there an easier and faster way of showing this? I thought about different parametrisation, into polar for examples but that didn't help very much. And this example was kinda trivial. How do you, in general, find what part of the sphere is covered through the gauss map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show directly that $n$ is surjective onto the upper hemisphere. Take an arbitrary vector $\nu=(a,b,c)$ in the hemisphere; i.e. $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $c>0$. We can write this as $\nu = c(a/c,b/c,1);$ so to make this parallel to $$n(x,y)=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}} (-y, -x, 1)$$ we should choose $y=-a/c, x=-b/c.$ Plugging these in to $n(x,y)$ we find $$n(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2/c^2+b^2/c^2}}(a/c,b/c,1)=c(a/c,b/c,1)$$ as desired. In the last equality we used both facts $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ (to reduce the square root to $\sqrt{1/c^2}$) and $c>0$ (so that $\sqrt{c^2} = +c$).

To show that this is the entire image, we just need to show that any other unit vector (i.e. $(a,b,c)$ with $c\le 0$) is not the image of any $(x,y)$, but this is clear: the $z$-coordinate of $n(x,y)$ is $(1+x^2+y^2)^{-1/2} > 0$.